# Tkinter add entry on basis of an answer of a OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using TKinter (I'm new with GUI tools), and I would like to know if it is possible to add (or activate) a entry with base on the answer of a option menu. Below is a part of the code

```
from Tkinter import *

win=Tk()

Label(win, text="Is This a Data Cube?",font='20').grid(row=14, column=0,sticky=W)
DataCubeValue = StringVar(win)
DataCubeValue.set("False")
DataCube = OptionMenu(win,DataCubeValue,"True","False")
DataCube.grid(row=15, column=0,sticky=W)
```

If the answer is `True` is choosen I would like to display this:

```
Label(win, text="X and Y values (x,y)",font='20').grid(row=14, column=1,sticky=W)
XYValue = StringVar(win)
XYValue.set("10,7")
XY =  Entry(win,textvariable=XYValue)
XY.grid(row=15, column=1,sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 0):

A central idea of GUI programming is to register code to be executed in reaction of user actions. Such code is usually named callback (the toolkit call it back depending on user actions on the interface).

You can bind to DataCubeValue changes with the following line. `callback` method (to be defined before) will be cause each time the value of DataCubeValue change.

```
DataCubeValue.trace("w", callback)
```

In the `callback` method, you can either choose to place the block of code with `Label` and `Entry` instantiation, but think that callback will be called every time the user change the OptionMenu value. You could either deactivate the OptionMenu once the user used it, but I would advise to  instantiate your widgets in the initial run, and just display or hide them from the callback.

```
def callback(*args):
    if DataCubeValue.get() == "True":
        label.grid(row=14, column=1,sticky=W)
        XY.grid(row=15, column=1,sticky=W)
    else:
        label.grid_forget()
        XY.grid_forget()
```